# Create a Grails Domain mapping for a foreign key that is connected to the composite primary key of another Domain

Tags: grails, groovy

How can I reference two columns (which is also its composite primary key) of a Grails Domain to the composite primary key of another Domain class? In this scenario, there is one-to-one relationship between `CEO` to`Agency` and `Agency` to `Branch`.

I can map easily `CEO` to `Agency` since it only involves one column: `CEO.id == Agency.ceo_id`. But I cannot map `Branch` to `Agency` using this two columns: `Agency.id == Branch.agency_id and Agency.main_branch_id == Branch.branch_id`.

```
class CEO {
    .....
}

class Agency {
    .....
    CEO ceo
    Branch mainBranch

    static mapping = {
        .....
        ceo column: 'ceo_id'
        /* Tried using this mapping but it doesn't work
        mainBranch {
            agencyId column: 'id',
            branchId column: 'main_branch_id'
        }
        */
        .....
    }
}

class Branch {
    .....
    Integer agencyId
    Integer branchId

    static mapping = {
        .....
        id composite: ['agencyId', 'branchId']
        .....
    }

    static constraints = {
        .....
        branchId unique: 'agencyId'
        .....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to use following technique for Agency class:

```
 class Agency {
     .....
     CEO ceo
     Branch mainBranch

     static mapping = {
     .....
     ceo column: 'ceo_id'
     columns {
        mainBranch {
            column name: "FirstName"
            column name: "LastName"
        }
     }
 .....
 }
```

Reference is [here](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/guide/GORM.html) - section 6.5.2.5 Composite Primary Keys.